# Как исправить ошибку "LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ"?

Tags: c++, ооп, visual-c++

Имеется два класса. Один из них содержит статический массив ссылок на экземпляры другого и реализует операцию добавления новых элементов в массив.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B;

class A {
private:
    static B* arr[5];
public:
    static void add(B* b, int i) {
        arr[i] = b;
    }

};

class B {
public:
    B() {};
};

int main() {
    B* bb = new B();
    A::add(bb, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

В итоге получается следующая ошибка:
main.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""private: static class B * * A::arr" (?arr@A@@0PAPAVB@@A)"
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём дело и как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Надо отдельно определить статический массив

```
B* A::arr[5];
```

[вне класса](http://ideone.com/XLkOVu).

Answer (score 1):

Объявление статического члена данных класса не является его определением и может даже иметь неполный тип. Из стандарта C++ (9.2.3.2 Static data members)

> 2 The declaration of a non-inline static data member in its class
>   deﬁnition is not a deﬁnition and may be of an incomplete type other
>   than cv void....

В отдельных случаях, когда используются, например, целочисленные статические константы, инициализированные при объявлении внутри определения класса, можно не определять данный статический чkен вне определения класса.

В вашем случае вы должны определить массив вне определения самого класса.

```
B* A::arr[5];
```